# How can I check what program is hogging the internet bandwidth?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I noticed my internet drops when my one of my friends computer always connects to the router. I used Windows network tab in the manager (CTRL+SHIFT+ESC) to confirm my theory. When my internet dropped, I checked my friends computer right away to confirm that there's a huge spike on the graph. The computer already has AVG, and I ran HiJackThis to see if there were any culprits, but nothing. So I want a program to see all traffic to see what is causing such a huge spike. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick first thing on the offending computer would be the resource monitor `C:\Windows\System32\resmon.exe` Then go to the "Network" Tab, When you don't see enough info, expand the "TCP connections" section with the `\/` arrows.
  Then Right click on the Column header line The one that says `| Image | PID | LocalAddress | etc`  and "Select Columns"  check mark `[x] send B/sec` and  `[x] receive b/sec`  or just total.  Now you have more info and can sort by activity, by clicking on the columns and scrolling to the top.

Added noise you might find useful: 
This same trick can be done in the Taskmanager to see I/O of specific programs , and processes Or Net total only.
In taskmanager "Processes" go to "VIEW" "Select Columns" , and select `I/O read bytes` `I/O Write bytes`, and `I/O other`.    If there was actually something odd going on via the network activity, the limited view of the task manager set with these columns can become useful also.

Answer (score 2):

Might be over kill, but Wireshark might help, its a packet capture program.

http://www.wireshark.org/

Note, that it'll probably have to run on his machine otherwise you'll only see his broadcast packets.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to reset your accesspoint.
Such a unrelated siconnections are caused by firmware bugs in router.
I do not see any spikes in task manager - could you elaborate which of 10 graphs in task manager spikes and is it up or down...

Answer (score 0):

[Try netbalancer](http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/), it shows all processes and programs that use network bandwidth in real time.

.